# Tomcat External Executable Call

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, glassfish, ejb

I am using an application that runs on Tomcat 5 environment. This application needs to call an external application (Delphi Executable). I am using the following command line to make the call:

```
Process pr = rt.exec(PatToDelphiExe);
pr.waitFor();
```

When I start tomcat as application, as application delphi exe is started as well, however, when the tomcat is started as a service, delphi exe is also started attached as a tomcat service "as a service".

**I need the delphi exe to be started as application even when the call is made through the tomcat service.**

I Also tried the code below from Apache lib with no success:

```
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(PathToDelphiExe);
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
executor.setExitValue(1);
executor.execute(cmdLine, resultHandler);
```

Comment: Curiously, Why are you not calling the exe from a RMI server as a standalone program and use a RMI client from tomcat to connect to the RMI server to use the services of the exe? Just throwing a random idea.